# How can one reserve a car at Bagan City prior to entering Myanmar?

Tags: international-travel, car-rentals, myanmar, bagan

I (French citizen with French, US and international driving licenses) would like to reserve a car for ~24 hours in [Bagan City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagan), Myanmar. I'm not in Myanmar yet and I would like to book the car before arriving to Myanmar. How can one reserve a car at Bagan City prior to entering Myanmar?

The first car rental company in Myanmar I have found, [Yoma Car Share](https://www.yomacarshare.com), doesn't let customers reserve cars before obtaining a Yoma Car Share member card, which according to their website may only obtained in one of the Yoma Car Share branches in  Myanmar.

The second car rental company in Myanmar I have found doesn't have any car in Bagan: https://www.europcar.com/en/car-rental/locations/myanmar-burma

FYI: [Is it illegal to drive a car by oneself as a foreigner in Myanmar?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/45479/31)

Comment: When I was in Myanmar a few years back, foreigners were not allowed to rent and drive cars. Has that changed?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Yoma Car Share seems ok with it. https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g294190-i9408-k12302225-Self_Drive_in_Myanmar_as_of_2018_early_2019-Myanmar.html reported it worked.

Comment: Hm. Everything I see still shows it not being allowed. If there is an accident (Myanmar roads are *scary*) it is likely you will be automatically at fault, and in loads of trouble.

Comment: That being said, e-bikes are not illegal; is there a reason you need a car in specific?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas As you mentioned, roads in Myanmar aren't the safest in the world. I prefer breaking a car than a leg.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas [Is it illegal to drive a car by oneself as a foreigner in Myanmar?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/45479/31)

Answer (score 2):

[This website](https://www.travelocity.com/Car-Rentals-In-Bagan.d500136.Car-Rental-Guide) (no affiliation) allows you to compare car prices and reserve the car in advance even paying later when outside Myanmar.

Another website that offers this is [here](https://www.expedia.co.uk/Compare-Cheap-Car-Hire-In-Bagan.d500136.Car-Hire-Guide), but there are many websites that offer this if you search *Bagan City reserve rental car*.

Comment: Thanks. Using your two links and selecting some dates, I get "Sorry, we're unable to find any cars at Nyaung-U (NYU) for the selected dates. Try a different pick-up location to find your ideal car." It seems that the typical car rental companies don't have any car in Bagan.